# How to link C library in Cmake file?

Tags: ros, third-party

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was using one ftdi library to communicate with robot, to run that piece of code i used to compile like

`gcc -o demo demo.c -L. -lftd2xx -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib`

Now i am using this C library in ROS, then how to link that library with ROS, What should I change in **CmakeLists.txt**
and how to write that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201258/how-to-link-c-library-in-cmake-file?/) by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add the path to the library to `target_link_libraries`

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-19**:
Ok. Means like this `target_link_libraries(odom ${catkin_LIBRARIES} /usr/local/lib)`,
Should I change **include directory** also?
Same problem is it possible to do in launch file?
What is `env` value? Is it same as `target_link_libraries`?

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-01-19**:
`/usr/local/lib` should be automatically added by cmake. You only have to add your special libraries, in your case ltd2xx I guess.
A launch file has nothing to do with linking. The `env` value is documented [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/env).

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-19**:
my library is ftd2xx and (-l) is option for library name. According to you it will search and path of that library automatically. is it?

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2015-01-19**:
target_link_libraries(odom ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ftd2xx) should work.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-01-20**:
Yes it searches automatically.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-20**:
I tried that one but it is showing error.

`imu.cpp:(.text+0x5c3): undefined reference to 'FT_GetLibraryVersion'`

`imu.cpp:(.text+0x671): undefined reference to 'FT_Open'`

`imu.cpp:(.text+0x6d4): undefined reference to 'FT_SetBaudRate'` 
How to write -rpath in CMakeLists.txt

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-01-20**:
You don't need `-rpath`
Where did you put libftd2xx.so?
Did you write `target_link_libraries(odom <path to libftd2xx.so> ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-20**:
@BennyRe I tried

```
target_link_libraries(odom /usr/local/lib/libftd2xx.a ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(odom ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ftd2xx)
```

and another combination too, still it is showing error

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-01-20**:
@KDROS You should make sure to only do one of those at a time. Otherwise I would say their suggestions should be working.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-20**:
@william I used one at a time, I am trying to say,none of them worked. What is the actual format?
Why it is showing error.